# Stored procedure taking too much time while execution

Tags: oracle, plsql

yesterday i attend a interview he asked me a question.
QUE:-i have table for example emp_tab and i create a procedure for displaying emp details from emp_tab. the problem is yesterday it took 30 min to execute but today it took 4 hrs to execute and he said data in emp_tab is same and procedure is same nothing is modified. how to you approach what is cause... nobody touched the program or table so what is the reason...

Comment: hm.. Probably somebody has touched table's indexes?

Comment: The question details describe troubleshooting approaches to an unexpected query performance issue, but your question title is about something different. Please update one or the other.